# how to get full cpu utilization from MXNET in mac os x ?

Tags: multithreading, mxnet

We are playing mxnet for a while. still couldnt get full cpu utilization as we have in tensorflow in default.

we have:
python 3.6
mxnet     1.2.1 pos1
mxnet-mkl 1.2.1 pos1

installed via pip (in Pycharm).
mac os x Sierra 10.12.6

we have only 2 core of the cpu used out of the 8 cores.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

MXNET has a number of environment variables that determine the thread count.  Try increasing MXNET_CPU_WORKER_NTHREADS.  (The default value is 1.)

For more information:

- [MXNET: Environment variables](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/faq/env_var.html#set-the-number-of-threads)
- [MXNET: Some tips for improving MXNET performance](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/faq/perf.html)